# Add Tab Background Color in VS code for Specific Tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I was looking for a way to add a tab background color to a few of the tabs **not only the activetab**.

I have 2 main requirements:

1. **I will initially choose which all tabs get what colors.**
2. **They should remain those colors even if I go to a different tab.**

I was taking help from [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color).
Can someone please provide a sample if its is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by using an extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mondersky.tabscolor

Comment: I actually have a bigger project in mind, this was a part of an extension that I am working on. I wanted that feature in my extension.